# eclipse-rcp : jface tableviewer cell traverse

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

There is a column which displaying row numbers, I want to stop user to traverse to cells in it using arrow keys.
[image]
In above picture, the cell with text "testDO3" is currently focused and highlighted, the row number column is used to select the whole row, so I want to make it not travsersable.

---

here is my own solution:

```
tv.getTable().addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener(){
            public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
                ViewerCell cell = focusCellManager.getFocusCell();
                if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_LEFT && cell.getColumnIndex() == 2){
                    e.detail = SWT.TRAVERSE_NONE;
                    e.doit = true;
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Assuming you also handle ARROW_RIGHT, then it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using JFace cell navigation, then sub-class `CellNavigationStrategy` and use in constructor of `TableViewerFocusCellManager`.